# Android layout compatibility

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem with my widget with target android-14. minSDKVersion is 7. Widget looks and work fine under 3.1-4.x but under 3.1 I have problem with displaying. When I change target in project.properties to target=android-7 I get error in my layout files:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').
```

I also have error in *.java files, R cannot be resolved to a variable.

I understand that errors but how can I change my code to work with all targets form 2.1.

Thanks for any help.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/myWidget"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal">  
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/myWidgetBackground"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/item1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/item2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The best practice is to compile the project against the targetSDK version which in your case is android-14

Comment: I did that, but when I do this and then install app on eg 2.1 its doesn't looks good.

Answer (score 2):

`match_parent` replaced `fill_parent` with 2.2 (API 8) if I am not mistaken. So replace it with `fill_parent` and it should work on 2.1 devices, too.

As you have errors in your xml files, the class R can't be generated and this results in the error you received.

Comment: Your right. However changing match_parent to older fill_parent and build over 4.0 didn't solve the problem. My background of widget still didn't shows up. It must be problem with some draw function maybe.. Still trying

Comment: You never have mentioned a background... could you add your layout code?

Comment: You should give your ImageView that contains the background a width with `fill_parent`. Not sure how `wrap_content` will be interpreted if there is no src mentioned.